# Mysql slow query , Lock_time and Rows_examined is 0

Tags: mysql, mysql-slow-query-log

table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `ID` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Content` mediumblob,
  `CRDateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `Time_INDEX` (`CRDateTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Value has 100 strs ,  Content field is empty , the table has 60000 rows

another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table has 0 row , it's a empty table , no delete and update\insert action , only select

some slow query in log like this:

Id: 14568

## Query_time: 10.935600  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0

SET timestamp=1484230695;
SELECT * FROM `table` 
 WHERE (`ID` = 'aaaaaaaa') LIMIT 2;

## Query_time: 11.700000  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1

SET timestamp=1486821357;
SELECT
`GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
COUNT(1) AS `A1`
FROM `table2` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE (`Extent1`.`name` = '24977496') AND ('24977496' IS NOT NULL)) AS `GroupBy1`;

windows server 2008 r2
mysql 5.6.19

On the peak , all table query have this problem

Comment: How big is the table. What is the structure of the table. Is there a index on ID?

Comment: `id is pk` , But its type is text ?

Comment: if it is big table data then you can select specific filed which you want and add index , if id primary key then then id = 'aaaa' i think not correct also

Comment: yes, id data type is CHAR(36) , and the table has 60000 rows , only 5 fields , very small , another table also has the same slow query , but the table has 0 row , it's a empty table , has 2 fields , id(pk,int) and name(varchar(11)) , in peak period time

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE`, so `DROP INDEX ID_UNIQUE` in both tables.